# Even Activity is declare im Manifest but it shows exception

Tags: android, android-manifest, declaration

I declare my activity in manifest file but it shows exception for me

```
<activity android:name="BuyClick"></activity>
```

I did not get what is happening  to my manifest file

Exception are as follow

```
                           02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                           02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.kt.pos/com.kt.pos.BuyClick}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                           02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1541)
                            02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
                            02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
                             02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
                             02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
                             02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
                              02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):   at com.kt.pos.POSMainActivity$1.onFinish(POSMainActivity.java:21)
                             02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):    at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:118)
                          02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                           02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                          02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                         02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                        02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                       02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                        02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                        02-04 12:33:52.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                    02-04 12:38:52.231: I/Process(1260): Sending signal. PID: 1260 SIG: 9
```

Comment: post startactivity surrounding code

Comment: <activity android:name="com.kt.pos.BuyClick"></activity> ??

Comment: @baboo .. com.kt.pos is my default package name which is declare in manifest as

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kt.pos"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

Comment: post code of BuyClick plz

Answer (score 4):

It should be either

```
<activity android:name=".BuyClick"></activity>
```

or

```
<activity android:name="com.kt.pos.BuyClick"></activity>
```

It needs to be fully qualified with the package name or preceded with a "." if it's in the main package.

Comment: @ Anup Cowkur... please see above comment

Comment: If you have declared the package then put a dot (".") before "BuyClick" as I have stated in the first code snippet in my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<activity android:name="com.kt.pos.BuyClick"></activity>
```

Always use your package name with activity before defining them in menifest.

Comment: @ paypal... please see above comment